# Reload page when upload complete

Tags: r, shiny, shinyalert

I have a shiny app for uploading CSV file. I used the function `sendSweetAlert` from `shinyWidgets` package to send custom message but I would like to reload the page when user clik on "Ok" button

[image]

I tried to use `shinyalert` from `shinyalert` package but i dont get the desired result.

This is what I did :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyalert)


ui <- fluidPage( 
  
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
            multiple = FALSE,
            accept = c("text/csv",
                       "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                       ".csv"),
            width = "80%")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  # a progress bar
  observeEvent(
    input$file1,
    {  withProgress(message = "Progress...",value = 0, {
      for (i in seq_len(50)) {
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        incProgress(1 / 50)
        
        setProgress(NULL, detail = paste(round(((i+1)*100/50),digits = 0),"%"))
      }
      
      setProgress(1, detail = "100%")
      
      # the custom message when progress reach 100%
      sendSweetAlert(
        session = session,
        title = "Great",
        text = "Done !",
        type = "success"
      )
      
      # my second attempt but doest work
      
      # shinyalert::shinyalert('Succes', callbackR = mycallback)
      # mycallback <- function(value) {
      #   "javascript:window.location.reload(true)"
      # }
      
      
    })}
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Hello, I'm wondering why you want to do this. I think reloading the page will restart the app from the beginning, so the csv will need to be uploaded again, right?

Comment: @bretauv Hello, yes and the user will upload another CSV files (if he want it). I  want to "reload" the app again after each upload

Comment: But then what is the interest of reloading the page right after the file is uploaded? I mean, I could understand if you wanted to reload after having done some data manipulation so that you have a "clean" app again, but what is the interest of reloading right after uploading something since reloading will remove the uploaded file? Sorry, this is not really about the technical aspect of your question, but I'm struggling to see the point

Comment: @bretauv I will add some data manipulation (at this moment I dont know what kind of manipulation but I will add it) that's why i want to "reload" the app after the file is uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `callbackJS` in `shinyalert()`:

```
server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  # a progress bar
  observeEvent(
    input$file1,
    {  withProgress(message = "Progress...",value = 0, {
      for (i in seq_len(50)) {
        Sys.sleep(0.1)
        incProgress(1 / 50)
        
        setProgress(NULL, detail = paste(round(((i+1)*100/50),digits = 0),"%"))
      }
      
      setProgress(1, detail = "100%")
      

      shinyalert::shinyalert('Succes', callbackJS = "function() {location.reload()}")
      
    })}
  )
  
}
```

With this, the page will reload when you click on "Ok" in the modal.